# Problem With Undesrtanding How Constructors Work

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, field

Hi can anyone explain how is b=16(value of an object 'o' field b) in the next code:

```
class T{
  int a=5;
  int b=++a;
  int c=++b;
  public:
   T(int p): a(p++), b(a*p){b+=a+c;}
};

int main(){
  T o(2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code as posted won't compile.

Comment: It would help to go through step by step and post what you think happens in each step. An answer can then tell you exactly which step diverges from your expectations.

Comment: @NeilButterworth After fixing the trivial typo, [it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eef8211ef417b2b4).

Comment: @user463035818 People discuss quirks of languages using examples like this all the time. If you think there's no point then keep it to yourself.

Comment: @Preston I get your point, but there are nicer ways to object than telling me that I should not share my opinion.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? What was the purpose of it?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that this code relies on the order of how the objects are declared in the class so it makes the initialization very brittle (if the order changes the output changes).

That said, when you do

```
T(int p): a(p++), b(a*p){b+=a+c;}
```

The compiler transform the constructor to

```
T(int p): a(p++), b(a*p), c(++b) {b+=a+c;}
```

because `c` was not specified so we grab it's initializer from the default one provided in the class body.  Class members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class body so in this case it will match how it is specified in the member initialization list.  So we will start with

```
a(p++)
```

which initializes `a` to `2` and increments `p` to `3`. Then

```
b(a*p)
```

initializes `b` to `6`. Lastly

```
c(++b)
```

increments `b` to `7` and then initializes `c` to `7`.  Then we run the body of the constructor so

```
b+=a+c;
```

becomes

```
b += 2 + 7
```

and since `b` is already `7` it becomes `16` by adding `9` to it. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

`p` argument is 2. In the initializer of `a`, `p` is incremented to 3, and `a` is initialized to the old value 2.

`b` is initialized to 2 * 3 == 6.

There is no initializer for `c`, so the default initializer is used. There, `b` is incremented to 7 and `c` is initialized to the same value.

Finally in the constructor body, the compound assignment adds 2 + 7 to `b` resulting in 16.